# Backbone.View render error. "TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand e.$"

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views

I am trying this code using Backbone and Underscore, and produces an error message in console:

> TypeError: invalid 'instanceof' operand e.$

Could someone please explain how I fix this code?

```
<div id="my-element"></div>
<script>
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el:'#my-element',
    initialize:function () {
        this.render();
    },
    render:function () {
        this.$el.html('Markup here');
        return this;
    }
});
var myView = new MyView();
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found explain [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766714/backbonejs-where-to-declare-the-function-inside-a-view)

This error is indicating that jQuery either didn't load or isn't on the page. 
so I fixed it.

```
<script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.2.1/backbone-min.js"></script>
```